# Cordova 6.4.0: android platform install Whitelist error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm setting up a first cordova projecct.

After installing globally Cordova and creting a first app repository 
am trying to  set up the android platform within this command:

**cordova platform add android --save**

But this action ends up by generation this error message:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 0.989 secs Failed to install
>   'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error:
>   /home/firas/Bureau/Cordova/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/firas/Bureau/Cordova/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5) Error:
>   /home/firas/Bureau/Cordova/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1

I have tried to remove and re-add the adroid platform , but the problem persists , also I have tried to install the whitelist plugin **(cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0 )**

but also I faced the same problem , and finish by not being able to build or run my first HelloWord app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears especially with Cordova 6.4.0 (latest until 31 December 2016) .

To solve this problem, simply uninstall Cordova and re-install it for the version 6.0.0 which affords more stability with the whitelist component.

Steps:

1. `npm uninstall -g cordova`
2. `npm install -g cordova@6.0.0`

Comment: Before that version the version was `6.2.0` is still working fine with all the command and plugins, so you can install this version too. We have found many issues with using the latest 6.4.0 version for old + new project of cordova.

Comment: @firasKoubaa I have the latest cordova 6.4.0 and i m able to add android platform with no issues. Guess u may have to dig deep to conclude

Comment: it may depends with which version of sdk u use , the conclusion comes from the non stability of this version relatively to the 6.0.0 or the 6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

- Update Cordova version
- Set Local Path
- [Cordova Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/)

Comment: i have the latest one : 6.4.0

Comment: local path set?

Comment: yeah local path also set

Comment: Do you have android studio?

Comment: yeah , something in the sdk build tools ?

Comment: run this command 
android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra  and cordova platform add android do it for another new folder