# Cordova - after update from 6.3.0 to 6.4.0 - require android sdk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, bamboo

Recently I've updated my cordova version to 6.4.0 and started to get error messages when trying to **install cordova-plugin-device on a machine that doesn't include android sdk** (the app includes platform ios + android).

The error:

```
04-Jan-2017 14:52:50    cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device@1.1.2
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/state.js:543
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    throw 'Error executing "' + pluginCommand + '":\n' + output;
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    ^
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Error executing "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device@1.1.2":
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.2" via npm
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-device':CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:222:19
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at fulfilled (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/nodemodules/q/q.js:834:54)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:857:14
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at runSingle (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at flush (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/OA-BAPP0-CR/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at combinedTickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:67:7)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    at process.tickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:98:9)
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
04-Jan-2017 14:52:51    Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory
(this is from the build machine that is failing)
```

I didn't see any changes to cordova-plugin-device and since the plugin install when fine up to the update of the cordova version I thought it might be related.
Is someone aware of any connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41427344/3840093

Comment: Thanks for your help. downgrade the version back to 6.3.0

Comment: Yes, it is only solution of these all problems for now :)